# Function compared width element

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, element

I am trying to retrieve the width of an element `sidebar` to compare it to an absolute value `250px` to adapt my menu, but I'm not sure how to continue.

I need to know when my menu is open or close to delete items when it's closed.
Sorry for the little information given at the start.

Full Code JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function toggleSidebar() {
    $(".button").toggleClass("active");
    $(".sidebar").toggleClass("widthSidebarJs");
    $(".sidebar-item").toggleClass("active");
  }

  $(".button").on("click tap", function() {
    toggleSidebar();
  });

  var maxSizeSidebar = 250;
  var widthSidebar = $(".sidebar").innerwidth(); 

  function displayForXsSidebar(){
    if (widthSidebar < maxSizeSidebar){
      $(".displayForXs").toggleClass("displayXs");
   }
 }

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      toggleSidebar();
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Interesting ... What is your question?

Comment: um: innerwidth <--- typo and where do you call displayForXsSidebar?

Comment: Call the function `displayForXsSidebar` to compare the width using this `displayForXsSidebar()`

Comment: What CSS rules affect `.sidebar`?  Particularly, which ones change its width?

Comment: Are you shure you can't accomplish your task using CSS? It's a better place to accomplish styling logic. Please give a better view of your problem so I can help in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

As I can guess, you need to add/remove `displayXs`-class on resize.
You can  try to add `resize()` event listener.

Something like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  if (widthSidebar < maxSizeSidebar){
    $(".displayForXs").addClass("displayXs");
  } else {
    $(".displayForXs").removeClass("displayXs");
  }  
})
```

But the better way is `@media`-queries in your `css`.

Comment: thank you but it's not when the window shrunk. that's when my menu opens and closes

Answer (score 0):

In you currently code, your function `displayForXsSidebar()` not will be run. but easily, try this, remove the function..

```
$(document).ready(function() { // when document ready, we calculate the width, is better.
  var maxSizeSidebar = 250;
  var widthSidebar = $(".sidebar").outerWidth();

    alert('you widthSidebar value right now is ' + widthSidebar );

    if (widthSidebar < maxSizeSidebar){
      $(".displayForXs").addClass("displayXs");
    } else {
      $(".displayForXs").removeClass("displayXs");
    }
});
```

live demo..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxSizeSidebar = 250;
  var widthSidebar = $(".sidebar").outerWidth();

    if (widthSidebar < maxSizeSidebar){
      $(".displayForXs").addClass("displayXs");
      alert('you widthSidebar value right now is ' + widthSidebar + ' so we add class displayXs');
    } else {
      $(".displayForXs").removeClass("displayXs");
      alert('you widthSidebar value right now is ' + widthSidebar + ' so we remove class displayXs');
    }

});
```

```css
.sidebar {
width: 240px; /* Change width here to 260px if you want */
}
.displayXs { background: #000; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
MY SIDEBAR</div>

<div class="displayForXs">
My displayForXs element
</div>
```